# How to include a Module's constants and variables?

Tags: ruby

I have a Module with a constant and variable.

I wonder how I could include these in a class?

```
module Software
  VAR = 'hejsan'

  def exit
    @text = "exited"
    puts @text
  end
end

class Windows
  extend Software
  def self.start
    exit
    puts VAR
    puts @text
  end
end

Windows.start
```

Is this possible?

Comment: the variable was, the constant was not possible to transfer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing exactly what you want is not possible. Instance variables are strictly per object.

This happens to do what you expect, but `@text` is set on `Windows` not `Software`.

```
module Software
  VAR = 'hejsan'

  def exit
    @text = "exited"
    puts @text
  end
end

class Windows
  class <<self
    include Software
    def start
      exit
      puts VAR
      puts @text
    end
  end
end

Windows.start
```

Comment: `include Software` like in my example will do it. It will only be included in metaclass - so you can use `VAR` from class methods but not instance methods. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 9):

Ruby 1.9.3:

```
module Software
  VAR = 'hejsan'

  module ClassMethods
    def exit
      @text = "exited"
      puts @text
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods

  end

  def self.included(receiver)
    receiver.extend         ClassMethods
    receiver.send :include, InstanceMethods
  end
end

class Windows
  include Software
  def self.start
    exit
    puts VAR
    puts @text
  end
end

Windows.start
```

In IRB:

```
exited
hejsan
exited
```

Comment: Can you please add a little explanation to your answer.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while.  Gosh, this isn't a great question or answer.  But you probably arrived here because you want to do something similar.  Perhaps if you ask a fresh question or elaborate on what it is you're looking for?

Comment: No,  it is a great answer but was looking for an explanation for something which I didn't understand. It will be very helpful if you can explain what is  included method, what is receiver, what is receiver.send :include and receiver.extend .

Comment: included: https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/included
Callback invoked whenever the receiver is included in another module or class.
In this case, receiver is the class it is being included into.
send: https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send
Invokes the method identified by symbol, passing it any arguments specified.